# updating sql row with new data

Tags: android, sql

I put some code together to have functionality of updating my sql rows but it doesn't work. Can anyone have a look at my code please and let me know where I am wrong?
I can post alternative code if necessary. Here is my dialog file which is supposed to update the row:

```
class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
MyDB dba;
private View editText;
private DiaryAdapter adapter;




  //  public EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday) {         //first constructor
  //      super(context);
  //      this.fragment_monday = fragment_monday;
  //  }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private List<String> fragment_monday;

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//Position is the number of the item clicked
//You can use your adapter to modify the item
adapter.getItem(position); //Will return the clicked item
}

public EditListItemDialog(Context context, DiaryAdapter adapter, int position) {
super(context);
this.fragment_monday = new ArrayList<String>();
this.adapter = adapter;
}






@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
dismiss();
try {
    saveItToDB();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}

private void saveItToDB() {
dba.updateDiaryEntry(((TextView) editText).getText().toString(), 1);
dba.close();
((TextView) editText).setText("");// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

MyDB file:

```
public class MyDB {
private static final String TABLE_NAME = null;
private static final String KEY_ID = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
private final MyDBhelper dbhelper;



// Initializes MyDBHelper instance
public MyDB(Context c){

    context = c;
    dbhelper = new MyDBhelper(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                        Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

}


// Closes the database connection
public void close()
{
    db.close();

}

// Initializes a SQLiteDatabase instance using MyDBhelper
public void open() throws SQLiteException
{

    try {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.v("Open database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
        db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

}

// updates a diary entry (existing row)
    public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title, long rowId)
    {

        ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
        newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);

        return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;

    }

// Reads the diary entries from database, saves them in a Cursor class and returns     it from the method
public Cursor getdiaries()
{
    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}


}
```

Comment: Please, post your MyDB class.

Answer (score 0):

dba object is not initialized and your try/catch get the crash. Initialize it with

```
dba = new MyDB(context);
```

in your EditListItemDialog constructor (Uncomment it and remove **List fragment_monday**) like this:

```
class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
MyDB dba;
private View editText;
private DiaryAdapter adapter;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {           
    super(context);
    dba = new MyDB(context);
}
```

Comment: when I try to initialize like this I get error: The constructor MyDB(EditListItemDialog) is undefined

Comment: do I still need to initialize dba as in first example? Because I get error. And When uncommenting constructor like this, rows still are not getting updated.

Comment: No, remove dba = new MyDB(this); in your onCreate method.

Comment: right, I did so. But the rows are not being updated still. I must be still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your saveItToDB method with:

```
private void saveItToDB() {
    dba.open();
    dba.updateDiaryEntry(((TextView) editText).getText().toString(), 1);
    dba.close();
    ((TextView) editText).setText("")
}
```

dba.open() is missing.

Comment: well found! it was missing indeed. But it doesn't solve the problem of saving data. Still not updating rows. Must be something obvious that I forgot I am sure of it.

Comment: Post your logcat for more info.